# How to set up year view for datepicker in The Events Calendar plugin?

Tags: plugins, the-events-calendar

I've installed this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Everything is great except one thing, I can't find where I can change datepicker view.

On front-end "Events-In" has this view when you click on it: http://screencast.com/t/eLUeN5tB

How can I set up to year view like this: http://screencast.com/t/5z02EpQFCRod
?

Comment: Had you asked plugin's developers? This sounds very specific to plugin and it seems to use own interface elements rather than something from WP core.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't gotten an answer yet. Yes, you are right, this is very specific to plugin, I've hoped that somebody maybe knew how to do that.